# Deleting Question After Answered

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions

This question was correctly answered by someone and then the OP deleted it.

[Is $xy y' = \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$ separable or non-separable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747214/is-xy-y-sqrty2-1-separable-or-non-separable)

Is there some rule against this?

It makes it appear that they are cheating on HW or something.

Also, for the person who answered it, is that really fair?

Comment: Hey, you're right! This happens from time to time. If you notice, you can flag a mod and we'll undelete it if we think the deletion is in bad faith. I've undeleted this question (not because I was the answerer --- I would have generally). And yes, it is unfair to the person who answered it. I might also mention that this doesn't come up if the answer is upvoted, as the OP cannot delete their own question if there are upvoted answers.

Comment: Ah, further, this user has done this before to other users. Good catch.

Comment: It is one reason to be generous in quickly up-voting an otherwise unloved only Answer on an on-topic Question, as this prevents the "bilking" behavior, taking the benefit of an Answer without contributing that content to other Readers.

Comment: Related: [Why do some users delete their questions after receiving an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/why-do-some-users-delete-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer)